# Multiplying changing variables in javascript and displaying

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm trying to make the **CPS Total:** display the current total amount of Shacks multiplied by the value of the ShackOut value. Can somebody please help me achieve this? In this case, the base value of CPS Total should be 0 but should increase by 1 for each Shack purchased (by clicking the button). [This number should update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN0cV.png)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
var Cash = 75;
var CPStot = 0;

var ShackCost = 50;
var Shack = 0;
var ShackTot = 0;
var ShackTotCost1 = 50;
var ShackOut = 1;

function buyShack() {
  if (Cash >= ShackCost) {
    Cash = Cash - ShackCost;
    Shack = Shack + 1;
    ShackCost = Math.round(ShackCost * 1.05);
    ShackCount = Shack;
    ShackTotCost1 = ShackCost;

    document.getElementById("Cash").innerHTML = Cash;
    document.getElementById("ShackTot").innerHTML = ShackCount;
    document.getElementById("ShackTotCost").innerHTML = ShackTotCost1;
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  Cash = Cash + Shack * ShackOut;
  document.getElementById("Cash").innerHTML = Cash;
}, 250);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Shacks: <span id="ShackTot">0</span><br> Cash: <span id="Cash">75</span><br>
    <button onclick="buyShack()" id="button">Click Me!</button><br> CPS Total: <span id="CPStotStart">0</span>
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your original code referenced an HTML element that didn't exist (as evidenced by the error in the JS console). It's not super-clear what actual issue you're having, if any, other than the incorrect DOM element ID. Please update your question to include better details.

Comment: Hello Dave, sorry for the unclear question. I want the number (circled in the linked image) to update and equal to the value of Shacks (counted using the ShackTot variable) multiplied by the output of Shacks (counted using the ShackOut variable).

Comment: Please restore the snippet so people can run the code. The code still references a non-existent DOM element.